# Choosing how many x axis labels display on an altair chart in python

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, altair

I have an altair chart where I am using mark_rectangle. I want to choose how many x axis labels are displayed to have the marks form squares in the visualization. Or perhaps I want to choose the range of the x axis labels. Right now there are far too many labels being displayed. Below I have an example of what I am trying to achieve and what my current output chart is. I apologize if the issue is due to something else, I am currently figuring out altair.

**My code currently:**

```
alt.Chart(temdf).mark_rect().encode(
x=alt.X('norm:O', title='', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, labelAngle=360)),
y=alt.Y('term:N', title='', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
color=alt.Color('norm:O', title='', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues'), legend=None),
facet=alt.Facet('title:N', title='',columns=3, header=alt.Header(labelOrient='bottom', labelPadding=15, labelAngle=360), 
sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field = 'title', order='ascending'))
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

[image]

**My current output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared that your x data is type `O`, meaning *ordinal*, i.e. ordered categories. This says that you want one distinct x bin for each unique value in your dataset. If you want fewer ordinal x bins, you should use a dataset with fewer unique values.

Alternatively, if you don't want each unique x value to have its own label, you can use the quantitative data type (i.e. `x=alt.X('norm:Q')`), or perhaps bin your data `x=alt.X('norm:O', bin=True)`. Be sure to bin your color encoding as well if you use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when using the [Simple Heatmap](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_heatmap.html) which requires the values to be ordinal (type O).

My solution was to conditionally format the label values such that all values were the empty string except for every Nth element.

For example:

```
x=alt.X('p:O', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr='floor(datum.value*100)%5==0 ? 
format(datum.value, ".2") : "" ')),
```

My variable 'p' takes values 0 to 1, so this multiplies by 100, rounds down to the nearest integer, and modulo 5 so that every 5th value is 0. When the condition is 0 we print the actual value, otherwise we print "".